# Login Exchange Office 365 in Office 2016 and from PC Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office, exchange-2016, outlook-2016

i have some issue here.
i have domain Active Directory xxx.id and domain Office 365 abcd.com

in WORKGROUP PC i can login my email Office 365 using Office 2016.

and if i login my email from Office 365 using PC with Active Directory domain xxx.id it will show Error :https://prnt.sc/tf5sb4

is my PC with Active Directory canot login email using Office 365 in Office 2016 because different domain with Active Directory and Office 365?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any solutions from these topics and articles?

[Adding email 365 account - An encrypted connection to your mail server is not available. Already added others without issues.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/adding-email-365-account-an-encrypted-connection/876e03d8-ebea-4d46-8a95-78cb2bc4d6fc)

[Account Setup fails for Outlook.com accounts](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/account-setup-fails-for-outlookcom)

[Outlook Auto Account Setup: Encrypted Connection not available](https://slipstick.com/outlook/config/outlook-auto-account-setup-encrypted-connection-not-available/)

[Exchange - An encrypted connection to your mail server is not available](https://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/Exchange+-+An+encrypted+connection+to+your+mail+server+is+not+available)

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by the Autodiscover-related registry data:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
Review the following possible DWORD values that may be located under the \Autodiscover subkey.
•   PreferLocalXML

•   ExcludeHttpRedirect

•   ExcludeHttpsAutoDiscoverDomain

•   ExcludeHttpsRootDomain

•   ExcludeScpLookup

•   ExcludeSrvRecord

•   ExcludeLastKnownGoodURL (only applies to Outlook 2010 version 14.0.7140.5001 and later versions)

•   ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint (only applies to Outlook 2016 version 16.0.6741.2017 and later versions)

If the issue persist, you could test and solve Outlook problems with SARA
Support and Recovery Assistant is a new tool that helps users troubleshoot and fix issues with various Office 365 apps and services. The app diagnoses common Outlook issues like account setup, connectivity issues, password issues, or Outlook stops responding or crashes.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-the-microsoft-support-and-recovery-assistant-e90bb691-c2a7-4697-a94f-88836856c72f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#/?env=ExRCA

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/9e2671d9-8de3-4965-b0fc-e210b7a33cd1/alternative-to-quotexcludescplookupquot-after-migration-to-office-365-for-business?forum=exchangesvrgenerallegacy

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers

Comment: Hello Jayce, sorry for late response.. i've try SARA in my PC and it like this for an hour https://prnt.sc/tkxish thankyou